# OpenModelica SimulationOptions 'variableFilter' not working with '^' exceptions

Tags: regex, variables, filter, output, openmodelica

To reduce size of my simulation output files, I want to give variable name exceptions instead of a list of many certain variables to the simulationsOptions/outputFilter (cf. [OpenModelica Users Guide / Output](https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/1.19/omedit.html#output)) of my model. I found the regexp operator "^" to fullfill my needs, but that didn't work as expected. So I think that something is wrong with the interpretation of connected character strings when negated.

Example:

1. When I have any derivatives `der(...)` in my model and use `variableFilter=der.*` the output file will contain all the filtered derivatives. Since there are no other varibles beginning with character `d` the same happens with `variableFilter=d.*`. For testing I also tried `variableFilter=rde.*` to confirm that every variable is filtered.
2. When I now try to except by `variableFilter=^der.*`, `=^rde.*` or `=^d.*`, I get exactly the same result as without using `^`. So the operator seems to be ignored in this notation.
3. When I otherwise use `variableFilter=[^der].*`, `=[^rde].*` or even `=[^d].*`, all wanted derivation variables are filtered from the ouput, but there is no difference between those three expressions above. For me it seems that every character is interpretated standalone and not as as a connected string.

Did I understand and use the regexp usage right or could this be a code bug?

Side/follow-up question: Where can I officially report this for software revision?

_
OpenModelica v.1.19.2 (64-bit)

Comment: Report it here: https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica

Comment: It might be because the names of the der variables are special. As far as I remember they are not saved as der(variable) but $DER.variable and our tools are interpreting that as der(variable).

Comment: I have checked, the variables are saved using der(variableName), the problem is how we handle the regular expressions (we do: ("^(" + string(variableFilter) + ")$")): https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/blob/master/OMCompiler/SimulationRuntime/c/simulation/simulation_runtime.cpp#L343

Comment: Thanks a lot for checking and your hint to the source code!
So the problem is definitely caused by addition of the two strings "^(" and ")$".
Do you see any option for fixing/circumventing this?
I want to use the exception for other specific variables than derivations and just took this as a working example for the community.
Shall this be put in a github report now?

Comment: Yes, make a github issue and we'll try to find a better solution than what we have now.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Adrian!
https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/9951